# Expansion of Integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(x)=\int^{2}_{0} (1+t) \exp\left(x\cos\left(\frac{\pi(t-1)}{2}\right)\right) dt
\end{equation}
show that
\begin{equation}
I(x)= 4+ \frac{8}{\pi}x +O(x^{2})
\end{equation}
as $x\rightarrow0$.

=> Using integration by parts, but its too complicated for me because of huge exponential term.
 please help me.

Comment: You have the tag [tag:taylor-expansion], so expand the integrand a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the change of variables $t\leftarrow2-t$ shows that 
$I(x)=\int_0^2(3-t)e^{x\,\cos(\pi(t-1)/2)}dt$, taking the half sum we conclude that
$$\eqalign{I(x)&=2\int_0^2\exp\left(x\cos\frac{\pi(t-1)}{2}\right)dt\cr
&=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\int_0^2\cos^n\left(\frac{\pi(t-1)}{2}\right)dt\cr
&=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nu du\cr
&= \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}W_n
}$$
where $W_n=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^nu du$ is the well-known Wallis integral. In particular, since
$W_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $W_1 =1$ we get
$$I(x)=4+\frac{8}{\pi}x+{\cal O}(x^2)$$