# Integration by expansion

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(x)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{0} \sin(x\sin t) \,dt
\end{equation}
show that
\begin{equation}
I(x)=  \frac{2x}{\pi} +O(x^{3})
\end{equation}
as $x\rightarrow0$.

=> I Have used the expansion of McLaurin series of $I(x)$ but did not work.
please help me.

Comment: The method is identical to the one from your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/758369/5531).

Comment: That's related to the [Struve Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just appeal to the Taylor expansion of $I(x)$ directly; clearly $I(0)=0$. Now,
$$ I'(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(x\sin{t})\sin{t}\,dt. $$
So,
$$ I'(0) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin{t}\,dt = \frac{2}{\pi}. $$
Also,
$$ I''(x) = -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x\sin{t})\sin^2{t}\,dt. $$
So, $I''(0)=0$.

Therefore,
$$ I(x) = I(0) + I'(0)x + \frac{I''(0)}{2}x^2 + O(x^3) = \frac{2x}{\pi} + O(x^3). $$

Answer (score 1):

$sin(x\cdot sint) = x\cdot sint - \dfrac{(x\cdot sint)^3}{3!} + ...$, and integrate term by term should give the answer.

Comment: $sin(x\cdot sint) = x\cdot sint - \dfrac{(x\cdot sint)^3}{3!} + ...$, 
then I guess I have to integrate term by term.
$ I(0)=0$. Now,
integrate $I(x)= x sint$ at $t =\pi$ and $t=0$ gives the answer but I really don't know why and how?